# Getting data from the database and assign it

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I have assigned the retrieved data (`ChancesLeft`) from the database, and assign it with the created variable. But when I check the created variable in the controller (which already assigned to the retrieved data (`ChancesLeft`) from the database, the value of created variable is always 0, even though I already called that retrieve function. But, when I check in the class which the retrieve function is, the value of created variable is not 0, but following the value of retrieved data (`ChancesLeft`).

My question is, how can I pass the value from the class to the controller? So that I can use it?

Code (SystemManager):

```
public void RetrieveChancesLeft(string Name)
        {
            MyModel context = new MyModel();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Name], [ChancesLeft] FROM [Credentials] WHERE [Name] = @Name";

                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            context.Chances = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ChancesLeft"]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
 SystemManager _sm = new SystemManager();

 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel context, string Name)
    {
        _sm.RetrieveChancesLeft(Name);

        if (context.Chances > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }

        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetStarted", "Home");
        }
    }
```

The problem is, whenever I run the program and enter the `Name` it always redirect to the `GetStarted` View, so that means that `context.Chances` is always 0, even though the `ChancesLeft` in the database is not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RetrieveChancesLeft function should store the local context object in your SystemManager object for retrieval or return the context to the caller. You can  change the return type of your RetrieveChancesLeft function to get the object passed to the controller:

```
public MyModel RetrieveChancesLeft(string Name)
    {
        MyModel context = new MyModel();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT [Name], [ChancesLeft] FROM [Credentials] WHERE [Name] = @Name";

            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        context.Chances = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ChancesLeft"]);
                    }
                }
            }

            conn.Close();

        }
        return context;

    }
```

And your controller:

```
    SystemManager _sm = new SystemManager();

 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel context, string Name)
    {
        context = _sm.RetrieveChancesLeft(Name);

        if (context.Chances > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }

        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetStarted", "Home");
        }
    }
```